# problem in web crawling using cheerio and axios

Tags: javascript, axios, web-crawler, cheerio

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

axios({
    // URL
    url: 'http://nstatic.dcinside.com/company/rules/service_policy.html',
    method: 'GET',
})
    // success
    .then(response => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
        const terms_of_use = $('div.cnt').text();
        console.log(terms_of_use)
    })
    // fail
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });


axios({
    // URL
    url: 'http://nstatic.dcinside.com/company/rules/info_policy.html',
    method: 'GET',
})
    // success
    .then(response => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
        const info_policy = $('div.cnt02').text();
        console.log(info_policy);
    })
    // fail
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });

// ***here is the problem***
axios({
    //URL
    url: 'http://nstatic.dcinside.com/company/rules/youth_policy.html',
    method: 'GET',
})
    // success
    .then(response => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
        const data = $('#bodyWrap2 > div.cnt03 > dl:nth-child(1)');
        const youth_policy = data.text();
        console.log('youth_policy');
    })
    // fail
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

Every modules are successfully applied.
Code doesn't work after 22th line.
Can anyone solve this problem for me? :(
This is my first time asking here, please give me nice answers.

There comes no error, and I can't guess WHY it workes like that.
This is a code for crawling http://nstatic.dcinside.com/company/rules/youth_policy.html
I should get text in "#bodyWrap2 > div.cnt03 > dl:nth-child(1)"

I tried this too
`const info_policy = $('dl:nth-child(1)').text();`

Comment: Friendly suggestion you shouldn't say "line 22" or so. You should point out where the error is to get accurate answers

Comment: Ty for your advice! I'll make better question next time.

Comment: @calvin0907 You can [edit] the current question. The code here works fine for me though. Try printing `youth_policy` rather than `'youth_policy'` to see the actual policy.